# SWT DateTime strange behaviour

Tags: java, swt

I'm using a SWT DateTime widget and got a very strange behaviour. If I choose any date out of the month "February", "April" or "June" the displayed date is the date I choosed but with month "January". In my datebase the right date is saved, only the displayed date in my editor is wrong. Other months are working fine. The following example is how I set my "Date"-Object within my "DateTime"-Object.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
dateTime.setYear(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
dateTime.setMonth(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
dateTime.setDay(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

I can't explain this behaviour. For me it seems like an error within the DateTime widget. Any tips how to avoid this?

Comment: Can you show what exactly you use as `date` for `calendar.setTime(date);`?

Comment: The strange behaviour continues: Today (2013-02-01) I tested it again and it works fine. But if I set my PC-Date to 2013-01-31 the problem occurs again. Same if I set my PC-Date to 2013-03-31. The problem seems to occur only on specific days. The date which I put into my calender is e.g. "2012-06-15 08:14:12.0" (`date.toString()`) and the widget displays "15.01.2012" if the locale PC-Date is set to 2013-01-31 here but the right value "15.06.2012" if the locale PC-Date is today (2013-02-01) ...

Comment: Solved the problem now. The solution is described in this bugzilla-thread: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=190254. The trick is to set the day_of_month before setting the month in my DateTime-Widget

Comment: @AnarchoEnte You should take the answer you posted as a comment and put it down below in that big "Your Answer" box. It is perfectly okay to provide the official answer to your own question. And hit the green checkmark to accept it. Readers will know the question is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem now. The solution is described in this bugzilla-thread: bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=190254. The trick is to set the day_of_month before setting the month in my DateTime-Widget